# Get only sim and device stored Contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

I want to display a list with the names (`GIVEN_NAME`, `FAMILY_NAME`) of contacts that are stored in the Device and in SIM (I want to exlcude Account contacts).

What I do now is:

1) I get all the Accounts in an `accountTypesArray`

2) I query RawContacts excluding the accounts

`String where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " NOT IN (" + makePlaceholders(accountTypesArray.length) + ") ";
                String whereArgs[] = accountTypesArray;`

`return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID},
                        where,
                        whereArgs, null);`

3) I query `DATA` with mimeType structured name

`String where = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE +
                            "' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " IN (" + makePlaceholders(contactIDsArray.length) + ") ";`

`return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            projection,
                            where,
                            contactIDsArray,
                            SORT_ORDER);`

The problem is when the `contactIDsArray` size is greater that 999 and SQLite throws too many SQL variables Exception.
Is there a more efficient way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires magic strings we've picked up from investigating different devices.

For SIM contacts run the following query:

```
String selection = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " IN ('vnd.sec.contact.sim', 'com.oppo.contacts.sim')";
String[] projection = { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
```

For device contacts, try the following:

```
String selection = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " IN ('vnd.sec.contact.phone', 'com.htc.android.pcsc', 'com.sonyericsson.localcontacts', 'com.lge.sync', 'com.android.huawei.phone', 'Local Phone Account')";
String[] projection = { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
```